# Custom string yup validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, formik, yup

I want to validate a string that must be of the format `x.xx.xxxxx`, the first character is required, followed by a period, then two characters also followed by a period and then another set of characters can be anything of any length

Comment: You might want to check the position of '.' , in your case '.' mush be present at index 1 and 4 according to 0 based indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out a RegExp pattern `/[^.]\.[^.]{2}\.[^.]+/` in the Node console which might help you.

It requires a single non-period character, followed by a period, followed by two non-period characters, followed by a period, followed by one or more non-period characters.

If 0 or more non-period characters are allowed in the last position, then it should instead be as follows, ...

`/[^.]\.[^.]{2}\.[^.]*/`

```
> pattern = /[^.]\.[^.]{2}\.[^.]+/
/[^.]\.[^.]{2}\.[^.]+/
> pattern.test('a.bc.d')
true
> pattern.test('a.b.d')
false
> pattern.test('a.bc.djfkflkjd483789374')
true
```

In the context of **yup** it looks like this documentation would enable you to use a regexp for validation... https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-message-string--function-schema